# How can multiple java processes share a single rolling log file

Tags: java, concurrency, command-line-interface, slf4j, log4j2

I have a java CLI program that uses SLF4J with log4j2 and a rolling file appender for logging. When multiple processes are running there appears to be problems when it's time for the file to rollover. The file is unable to be moved and/or deleted and an ERROR is printed to stdout. Is there some trick to use a single log file with multiple processes? Do we need to use a single file per process? I just realized this was the first time I'd tried doing it as we'd used a daemon in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-174 it's a known limitation of the RollingFileAppender. FileAppender does not have this problem. Our solution is to have a per process UUID with one log file per process using a FileAppender.